# Is there a way to monitor kube cron jobs using prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Is there a way to monitor kube cronjob?

I have a kube cronjob which runs every 10mins on my cluster. Is there a way to collect metrics every time my cronjob fails due to some error  or notify when my cronjob has not been completed after a certain period of time?

Answer (score 20):

I'm using these rules with [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/cronjob-metrics.md):

```
groups:
- name: job.rules
  rules:
  - alert: CronJobRunning
    expr: time() -kube_cronjob_next_schedule_time > 3600
    for: 1h
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      description: CronJob {{$labels.namespaces}}/{{$labels.cronjob}} is taking more than 1h to complete
      summary: CronJob didn't finish after 1h

  - alert: JobCompletion
    expr: kube_job_spec_completions - kube_job_status_succeeded  > 0
    for: 1h
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      description: Job completion is taking more than 1h to complete
        cronjob {{$labels.namespaces}}/{{$labels.job}}
      summary: Job {{$labels.job}} didn't finish to complete after 1h

  - alert: JobFailed
    expr: kube_job_status_failed  > 0
    for: 1h
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      description: Job {{$labels.namespaces}}/{{$labels.job}} failed to complete
      summary: Job failed
```

Comment: This has the problem that it alerts indefinitely, since CronJobs will keep the jobs around until the history limit is hit.

Answer (score 18):

The tricky part here is the cronjobs themselves have no useful status, you have to match them to the jobs they create. I've written up an article on how to achieve this:

https://medium.com/@tristan_96324/prometheus-k8s-cronjob-alerts-94bee7b90511

The article goes into a bit of detail as to how things work, but the alert config is as follow:

```
groups:
- name: kube-cron
  rules:
  - record: job_cronjob:kube_job_status_start_time:max
    expr: |
      label_replace(
        label_replace(
          max(
            kube_job_status_start_time
            * ON(exported_job) GROUP_RIGHT()
            kube_job_labels{label_cronjob!=""}
          ) BY (exported_job, label_cronjob)
          == ON(label_cronjob) GROUP_LEFT()
          max(
            kube_job_status_start_time
            * ON(exported_job) GROUP_RIGHT()
            kube_job_labels{label_cronjob!=""}
          ) BY (label_cronjob),
          "job", "$1", "exported_job", "(.+)"),
        "cronjob", "$1", "label_cronjob", "(.+)")

  - record: job_cronjob:kube_job_status_failed:sum
    expr: |
  clamp_max(
        job_cronjob:kube_job_status_start_time:max,
      1)
      * ON(job) GROUP_LEFT()
      label_replace(
        label_replace(
          (kube_job_status_failed != 0),
          "job", "$1", "exported_job", "(.+)"),
        "cronjob", "$1", "label_cronjob", "(.+)")


  - alert: CronJobStatusFailed
    expr: |
      job_cronjob:kube_job_status_failed:sum
      * ON(cronjob) GROUP_RIGHT()
      kube_cronjob_labels
      > 0
    for: 1m
    annotations:
      description: '{{ $labels.cronjob }} last run has failed {{$value }} times.'
```

The jobTemplate must include a label called `cronjob` that matches the name of the cronjob object.

Answer (score 6):

The way to monitoring cronjobs with Prometheus is to have them push a metric indicating the last time they succeeded to the pushgateway. You can then alert on if the cronjob hasn't succeeded recently enough.

Comment: Using timetamps on the metrics is discourgaged. Have a metric whose value is a timestamp (such as `process_start_time_seconds`) is fine.

Answer (score 6):

All answers so far are unaware of namespaces, and are dependent on custom labeling in the `Job`.

The latter can be fixed as kube-state-metrics version 1.6.0 introduced a new metric `kube_job_owner` which solves the problem matching `Job`s and `CronJob`s.

NOTE: In kube-state-metrics 1.4.0 the `job` label was renamed to `job_name` to avoid a label collision with Prometheus.

```
clamp_max(
  max by (namespace, owner_name, job_name) (
    max by (namespace, owner_name, job_name) (
      kube_job_status_start_time
      *
      on (job_name) group_left(owner_name) max by (namespace, owner_name, job_name) (kube_job_owner{owner_kind="CronJob"})
    )
    ==
    on (namespace, owner_name) group_left max by (namespace, owner_name) (
      kube_job_status_start_time
      *
      on (job_name) group_left(owner_name) max by (namespace, owner_name, job_name) (kube_job_owner{owner_kind="CronJob"})
    )
  ),
  1
)
*
on (namespace, job_name) group_left kube_job_status_failed
```

The output can be further improved by renaming the `owner_name`
label to `cronjob` by surrounding the expression with

```
max without (owner_name) (
  label_replace(
    <expression from above>
  ,
  "cronjob", "$1", "owner_name", "(.+)"
  )
)
```

(the `label_replace()` function *adds* a new `cronjob` label, while `max()` drops the `owner_name` label)

Comment: Could you explain the query?

Comment: @PerC This is not namespace safe, if you have two cronjobs in two different namespaces of the same name, this query breaks with "found duplicate series for the match group".  I'm trying to craft a fix but it's fairly complex, could you perhaps craft a fix?

Comment: I figured out the fix for anyone curious.  Change both instances of "on (job_name)" to "on (job_name, namespace)".  Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You can get the info you want from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/Documentation/job-metrics.md).

CronJobs create Jobs on a schedule, so you can simple look at kube_job_status_failed for the jobs that are created, one caveat is the job name has an epoch time at the end.

To ensure alerts resolve themselves I'm using the following query in alert manager:

```
increase(kube_job_status_failed{job=~"mytestjob-.*"}[5m]) > 1
```

My cron is:

```
*/5 * * * *`, and I set `backoffLimit: 2
```

to limit number of failures per run.

Answer (score 2):

The kube-state-metrics exporter also includes various CronJob related metrics: https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/Documentation/cronjob-metrics.md, but unfortunately doesn't seem to include success CronJob success/failure.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simplify this medium post (label_replace was not working for me for some reason)
https://medium.com/@tristan_96324/prometheus-k8s-cronjob-alerts-94bee7b90511

My cron query looks like this (we have "component" labels on all cronjobs instead of "cronjob", but you can use your favorite label)

```
clamp_max(max(
    kube_job_status_start_time
    * ON(job) GROUP_RIGHT()
    kube_job_labels{label_component!=""}
  ) BY (job, label_component)
  == ON(label_component) GROUP_LEFT()
  max(
    kube_job_status_start_time
    * ON(job) GROUP_RIGHT()
    kube_job_labels{label_component!=""}
) BY (label_component), 1) * ON(job) GROUP_LEFT() 
kube_job_status_failed
```

Plug this into the prometheus expression dashboard to make sure you get results (1 means the cron failed the last time, 0 means it succeeded or hasn't run yet).

For alerting, add `!= 0`, and the query will return with ANY cronjob that failed.

Comment: This gives an error: `Error executing query: found duplicate series for the match group`

Comment: won't that alert clear up as soon as a job starts again (scheduled, not retry)? So if a job is failing because it's really broken, you will see the alert clear up until the next failure?

Comment: kube_job_labels return me below result. I don't know why label_cronjob is not working on my machine. 
kube_job_labels{instance="kube-state-metrics.kube-system.svc.cluster.local:8080", job="kube-state-metrics", job_name="helloworld-28184784", namespace="default"}

Answer (score 0):

There is a way how to monitor single Kuberentes cronjob:

```
min((kube_job_status_succeeded{namespace="default"} unless on (job_name) kube_job_status_active == 1) * on(job_name, namespace, env) group_left(owner_name,k8s) kube_job_owner{owner_kind="CronJob", owner_name="cronjob-name-here"}) or on() vector(1)
```

If cronjob does not exist or running, graph/metric shows 1(success). In case of job failure, metric returns 0.

However, if you have failed jobs history for cronjob, need to check why they failed and remove them to get actual result. Quite good solution for monitoring, but requires manual intervention. Of course, it is possible to adjust cronjob history limit and avoid such situation.